# How can I calculate the annualised growth rate for an irregular investment?

Tags: calculation, portfolio, spreadsheet, growth

I have a portfolio, which I invest in monthly. Depending on my circumstances, the monthly amount changes from time to time (perhaps every two years or so).

I want to calculate the annualised growth rate of my investment. At the moment I'm using Excel's [RATE](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-rate-function) function, like this:

`=RATE(num_months,-average_monthly_investment,-present_value,initial_value)`

This is OK as an approximation but I'm looking for a more accurate result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recapping your method with a simple example

```
initialvalue = 1000
m1start = 100
m2start = 100
m3start = 100
v3end = 1500

=RATE(3,-100,-1000,1500,1)
```

> ```
> 0.0528704
> ```

The calculated rate is 5.29% per period.

This is equivalent to solving the equation below.

[image]

```
∴ v3end = (100 (1 + r) ((1 + r)^3 - 1))/r + initialvalue (1 + r)^3

∴ r = 0.0528704
```

The most accurate method is to use the time-weighted return.  However, this requires valuations at the end of each period.

```
initialvalue = 1000
m1start = 100
v1end = 1158
m2start = 100
v2end = 1325
m3start = 100
v3end = 1500

(1158/(1000 + 100)*1325/(1158 + 100)*1500/(1325 + 100))^(1/3) - 1 = 0.0528726
```

If you have varying payments you can put them into the time-weighted return calculation.

```
initialvalue = 1000
m1start = 90
v1end = 1147
m2start = 130
v2end = 1344
m3start = 80
v3end = 1500

(1147/(1000 + 90)*1344/(1147 + 130)*1500/(1344 + 80))^(1/3) - 1 = 0.0527103
```

If you don't have periodic valuations you can use the money-weighted return.  This method discounts all the amounts to present value.

Solving for `r`

```
(1000 + 100)/(1 + r)^0 + 100/(1 + r)^1 + 100/(1 + r)^2 = 1500/(1 + r)^3
```

> ```
> r = 0.0528704
> ```

And with varying payments.

```
(1000 + 90)/(1 + r)^0 + 130/(1 + r)^1 + 80/(1 + r)^2 = 1500/(1 + r)^3
```

> ```
> r = 0.0527379
> ```

Note this may well differ from the time-weighted return.

For further reading see [How to Calculate your Portfolio's Rate of Return](https://www.pwlcapital.com/pwl/media/pwl-media/PDF-files/Justin%20Bender%20Assets/How-to-Calculate-your-Portfolio-s-Rate-of-Return_v03linked.pdf).

Annualise by

```
12*r for nominal annual return compounded monthly
```

or

```
(1 + r)^12 - 1 for effective annual rate of return
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the detail. If I've understood you correctly, what I need to do is:
* Divide my portfolio into timeslots, and ensure that for the duration of each timeslot the investment is constant.
* Calculate the rate of return over each timeslot.
* Use the Time-Weighted Rate of Return formula to calculate an overall rate of return.

Comment: @MarkBarnes Yes, that's the most accurate method because it's using the real returns and taking the [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean).  The periods don't need to be equal, e.g. for 10% per quarter: calculating from a six-month return plus two quarters is `(1.21*1.1*1.1)^(1/4) - 1 = 0.1`